# Как и где создается интерфейс и дизайн приложения написанного на Python?

Tags: python, интерфейс, дизайн

Как например из простого терминального кода наподобие шахмат делают какие-то *3D* фигуры передвижения и так далее, а из терминального калькулятора - плавный и красивый калькулятор.

Comment: в гугле можно ввести python ui или gui (user interface) и будет ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания UI необходимо использовать библиотеку или фреймворк, который позволяет отрисовывать графические элементы делая соответсвующие вызовы ОС.

Самый известный в мире Python, но далеко не самый лучший, это [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) . Он входит в стандартную библитеку и не требует установки дополнительных модулей.

То, что я часто вижу вокруг как ответ по умолчанию для UI на Python - это биндинг (возможность вызывать код одного языка из другого языка) [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) к Python: [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro). В том числе PyQt3D. Qt написал на С++, но ничто не мешает набросать окошко в QtDesigner, а логику его поведения реализовать на Python.

Другая известная библиотека - [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/). Но я никогда её не использовал, не могу сказать ничего определённого.

Answer (score 0):

Самое легкое - визуальное программирование на PyQT5 с инструментом designer(Юзать можно только 2 версию Пайтона)

Comment: И зачем оно нужно, если только для этой доисторической версии?